# Keyboard disappear after navigation

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, xcode9

Since the release of ios11 and Xcode9, when the keyboard is open and I push to a new `UIViewController`, the keyboard disappear after the new controller appear like this :

[image]

Why ?

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Yes but I don't want to make it appear, I want it to disappear at the same time as my controller

Comment: So make it resignFirstResponder before changing the controller

Comment: Thanks it work, but I don't understand why in swift 3, I didn't have this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this seems to be a new feature, which is logic in my option because when you press the back button you will come back to the same state as you were in before you pushed to the new `viewController`. Any how to solve it do as [@LeoDabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) suggested and call either `resignFirstResponder` or `self.view.endEditing(true)` before you leave the viewController.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```